# How do you call javascript inside of XUL through Firebreath?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, npapi, firebreath

I have written some javascript for my firefox extension in the XUL. This overlay has some cleanup functionality and I would like to be able to call the function through my NPAPI dll created via Firebreath.

I know that Firebreath has an example calling the "alert" function by doing the following:

```
// Retrieve a reference to the DOM Window
    FB::DOM::WindowPtr window = m_host->getDOMWindow();

    // Check if the DOM Window has an alert peroperty
    if (window && window->getJSObject()->HasProperty("window")) {
        // Create a reference to alert
        FB::JSObjectPtr obj = window->getProperty<FB::JSObjectPtr>("window");

        // Invoke alert with some text
        obj->Invoke("alert", FB::variant_list_of("This is a test alert invoked from an NPAPI Plugin"));
    }
```

The above code works so I've modified the Invoke to call my javascript function.

```
obj->Invoke("cleanupCode", FB::variant_list_of("0"));
```

This does not work and is confusing me on how I should be calling my javascript function.

Comment: Are you injecting the plugin into websites or loading it in the XUL?

Comment: My plugin is loaded into the XUL for the extension.

Answer (score 0):

How does your DOM look out ? Does window contain function named cleanupCode ? Maybe you can check it with firebug.

Comment: Window does not contain said function. The script is inside of the XUL of the extension.